# Unable to geocode, throwing an error as "The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found"

Tags: google-maps, geocoding, google-geocoding-api

This is the URL I have used in one of very old project but I checked this URL and fount that this is not working and throwing an error as: The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.

http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?output=xml&q=New+York

but this works fine

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=New+York&sensor=false.

What is the difference? Why first URL not working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first URL was used by version 2 of the Google Maps API which is not available any more since 2013. So the first URL is not working any more because it's not existing. You have to use the second URL (which is part of version 3).